# Convert factor of format Hh Mm Ss to time duration

Tags: r, datetime

I'm working with a data frame that has a variable called "Duration" with values in the format:

1h 7m 46s

0h 16m 41s

..and so on.  The column is formatted as a "factor" by default, and I'm wondering how to convert it to an actual duration.  I'd like to be able to compute averages and sums of the durations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider converting the times to strings with an [`as.character()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/character.html) cast.  Once your times are strings you can convert them into [`DateTime`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html) objects with the [`strptime`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) command, e.g.

```
> s <- "1h 7m 46s"
> tfmt <- "%Hh %Mm %Ss"
> t1 <- strptime(s, format=tfmt)
> s <- "0h 16m 41s"
> t2 <- strptime(s, format=tfmt)
```

Having the data in this format is handy as there are then tools for working with them

```
> t1
[1] "2015-01-30 01:07:46"
> t2
[1] "2015-01-30 00:16:41"
> t1 - t2
Time difference of 51.08333 mins
> difftime(t1, t2, units="secs")
Time difference of 3065 secs
```

Answer (score 5):

You can extract the hours, minutes, and seconds as follows:

```
x <- c('1h 7m 46s','0h 16m 41s')
hours <- as.numeric(gsub('^(?:.* )?([0-9]+)h.*$','\\1',x))
minutes <- as.numeric(gsub('^.* ([0-9]+)m.*$','\\1',x))
seconds <- as.numeric(gsub('^.* ([0-9]+)s.*$','\\1',x))
duration_seconds <- seconds + 60*minutes + 60*60*hours
```

the pattern for minutes is translated as: Starts with (`^`) zero or more(`*`) characters(`.`), followed by a space (), followed by 1 or more(`+`) digits(`[0-9]`) followed by the letter m (`m`) followed by zero or more(`*`) characters(`.`) to the end of the string(`$`)

Bonus: the `(?:.* )?` in the regex for hours is a non-capturing group(`(?: )`), which consumes zero or more (`*`) chartacters (`.`) followed by a space ().   Note that because `(?:.* )?` is a non-capturing gruop.  `\\1` still referrs to the number string.

Comment: This would only match the first digit - e.g, for the string "60 m", minutes will equal 0 because the first .* after the caret (^) is greedy. 

It should be:
 as.numeric(gsub('^(\\d+) m.*$','\\1', x))

Comment: Excellent point about the capture group, but your regex doesn't work either.   I added a space character to mine and now it works as expected.   In retrospect, a better solution would be to match the whole expression and capture all the values at once, like so: `strsplit(gsub('\\s*(\\d+)h\\s+(\\d+)m\\s+(\\d+)s\\s*$','\\1,\\2,\\3',"14h 3m 20s"),",")`