# R: convert text duration ("..d ..h ..m ..s") into seconds

Tags: regex, r, duration

Trying to convert the following durations into seconds

```
x <- "1005d 16h 09m 57s"
x1 <- "16h 09m 57s"
x2 <- "06h 09m 57s"
x3 <- "09m 57s"
x4 <- "57s"
```

I've modified the answer from Jthorpe in this post [Convert factor of format Hh Mm Ss to time duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244665/convert-factor-of-format-hh-mm-ss-to-time-duration).

```
days <- as.numeric(gsub('^*([0-9]+)d.*$','\\1',x3))
hours <- as.numeric(gsub('^.*([0-9][0-9])h.*$','\\1',x3))
minutes <- as.numeric(gsub('^.*([0-9][0-9])m.*$','\\1',x4))
seconds <- as.numeric(gsub('^.*([0-9][0-9])s.*$','\\1',x4))
duration_seconds <- seconds + 60*minutes + 60*60*hours + 24*60*60*days
```

However, this is only working with x, but not x1-x4. Now, I know I can probably use if logic to get around the issue, but is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can change the space character (`\\s+`) with `+` using `gsub`, then we can replace 'd', 'h', 'm', 's' with `gsubfn` and loop through the output and evaluate the string.

```
library(gsubfn)
v2 <- gsubfn("[a-z]", list(d="*24*60*60", h = "*60*60", m = "*60",
        s="*1"), gsub("\\s+", "+", v1))
unname(sapply(v2, function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
#[1] 86890197    58197    22197      597       57
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c(x, x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

Comment: @ akrun, WOW, I LOVE this. I'll spend sometime trying to get my head around the second part. haha

Comment: that is a brilliant solution to a common and ugly problem.

Comment: @ akrun, I got myself into another trouble with this approach. I'm using data frame df, then df$v3 <- unname(sapply(v2,....)), df$v3 was created as a list. I tried to use df$vs <-as.data.frame(uname(...)), it gives the following error, "arguements imply differeing number of rows: 1,0". Any suggestion?

Comment: @woshishui  It must be because there are more than one elements that result as a `list` output.  Can you show a small data that shows the problem?  What is the output from 'v2'?

Comment: @ akrun. the list is caused by blank entries in duration (change x4<-""), unname(sapply) put this into a list. It can be resolved by ifelse(duration=="", "0", gsubfn(...)). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
ifelse(is.na(your_exp),0)
```

So that whenever `na` is the output of your expression it becomes `0`.

Eg:

```
days <- ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(gsub('^*([0-9]+)d.*$','\\1',x1))),0)
hours <- ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(gsub('^.*([0-9][0-9])h.*$','\\1',x1))),0)
minutes <- ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(gsub('^.*([0-9][0-9])m.*$','\\1',x1))),0)
seconds <- ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(gsub('^.*([0-9][0-9])s.*$','\\1',x1))),0)
```

Output:(after `duration_seconds <- seconds + 60*minutes + 60*60*hours + 24*60*60*days`)

```
> duration_seconds
[1] 58197
```